# How do I find R without knowing anything about it?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: circuit]

Given this circuit, how do I find \$R_1\$ and the gain of the gain G of the voltage-controlled current source if \$V_2 = 8\text{ V}\$ and the 20 V voltage source supplies 4 W of power?

I tried using the current divider formula to find \$R_1\$ but ended have having a negative resistance, so I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

Comment: Apply ohm's law in the centre branch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed step by step.
Having v2 gives the current in the R1 branch so you can deduce R1 since all voltages are known.
Then having the power you get the total current and you can deduce the dependent current source and so on.

Comment: what do you mean all voltages are known? I don't know the voltage of R1

Comment: I also know what he said, having the 20ohms and R1 same current and i got stuck from there. i tried using current divider formula since that was made sense to me but ended up getting negative. That's why I asked here.

Comment: So are you familiar with Ohm's law?

Comment: yes, i am familiar with it

Comment: thats why im confused, i only got the current from the 25ohm resistor, how can i get the value of resistance without the voltage?

Comment: You are already told in the answer that you have the voltage. Please mark every voltage and current you already know in the circuit and you will hopefully see it.

Comment: is the voltage just 12V? i overthinked this way too much. Thank you!

Comment: @AedenSchmidt We don't hand out homework solutions here. Show us all of your work, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course). Secondly, we don't answer homework questions but I saw that you've already accepted the answer so I will show a general method of solving this question.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOOjJs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_1\$ and \$\text{I}_\text{i}\$:

- $$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag4$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\left(1-\text{n}\cdot\text{R}_2\right)\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code (and it is not very hard to solve it by hand):

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Ii + n*V1, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I1 == V1/R2}, {V1, Ii, 
   I1}]]

Out[1]={{V1 -> (R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2), Ii -> (Vi - n R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2), 
  I1 -> Vi/(R1 + R2)}}
```

---

So, when we know that voltage \$\text{V}_2\$ we get for \$\text{R}_1\$:

$$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{V}_1}-1\right)\tag6$$

And the power from the voltage source is given by:

$$\text{P}_{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\text{V}_\text{i}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\left(1-\text{n}\cdot\text{R}_2\right)\text{V}_\text{i}^2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}^2-\text{P}_{\text{V}_\text{i}}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}^2}\tag7$$

Using your values, we will find:

$$\text{R}_1=\frac{75}{2}=37.5\space\Omega\space\wedge\space\text{n}=\frac{3}{200}=0.015\tag8$$